# Closure in for loops & array in js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple loop:

```
raw_data=[
    {id:1, val:[1,2,3]},
    {id:2, val:[4,5,6]},
    {id:3, val:[7,8,9]}
]

arr=[]
buffer=[]
for(let i = 0; i < raw_data.length; i++) {
    for (let j=0; j<raw_data[i]['val'].length; j++) {
        buffer.push(
            raw_data[i]['val'][j]
        );
    }   
    arr.push(
        buffer
    );
}

console.log(arr)
```

I expected to have:

```
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

But got instead:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I've read about closure but dont understand why its related to this problem.
Whats wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that buffer is an array which makes it a reference type, which means when you add it to your array it adds a reference to buffer not the value.

```js
var a = []
b = a;
a[0] = 888;
console.log(b)
```

As you can see here, when I edit a, i edit b.

Try this

```js
raw_data=[
    {id:1, val:[1,2,3]},
    {id:2, val:[4,5,6]},
    {id:3, val:[7,8,9]} ]

arr=[];
buffer=[];
for(let i = 0; i < raw_data.length; i++) {
    for (let j=0; j<raw_data[i]['val'].length; j++) {
        buffer.push(
            raw_data[i]['val'][j]
        );
    }   
    arr.push(
        [...buffer]
    ); }

console.log(arr);
```

`[...buffer]` creates a copy. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this: after you have pushed  `buffer` to `arr`, you continue with the second iteration where you keep pushing new values to `buffer`. But because `arr[0]` now also is a reference to that `buffer`, you are actually affecting what you see via `arr[0]`!

So, the solution is to create a new buffer in each of the outer iterations, which takes the values from the previous buffer:

```js
let raw_data=[
    {id:1, val:[1,2,3]},
    {id:2, val:[4,5,6]},
    {id:3, val:[7,8,9]}
]

let arr=[];
let buffer=[];
for(let i = 0; i < raw_data.length; i++) {
    buffer = [...buffer]; // copy into a new location!!
    for (let j=0; j<raw_data[i]['val'].length; j++) {
        buffer.push(
            raw_data[i]['val'][j]
        );
    }   
    arr.push(
        buffer
    );
}

console.log(arr)
```

NB: you should define your variables always with `var`, `const` or `let`.